# Restart master in physical replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication, postgresql-12, pg-cron

I have 2 servers involving `master-slave` replication (physical replication).

I see the replication using `select * from pg_replication_slots;` there is a record saying :

```
user : rep_user`

application : 12/main

state : streaming
```

I have to change `postgresql.conf` on the master to enable `pg_cron` extension so I need to restart the master.

Is it safe to just restart it using : `sudo service postgresql stop` followed by `sudo service postgresql start` ? Do I have to drop the replication first before restarting?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always safely restart the primary server with streaming replication. The standby will stay up and will try to reconnect to the primary. As soon as the primary is back up, the standby will connect again.

If you get WAL receiver timeouts, as your comment suggests, you can increase `wal_receiver_timeout` on the standby.

Comment: thanks @LaurezAlbe. I just restarted it. And it is confirmed that the service can be restarted without any further implication

Comment: Just curious. The streaming replication started 21 hours later (without any intervention, automatically). But, why does it take so long to start? I was thinking that the `replication` fails. I do `select * from pg_stat_replication` and there is no single record. Suddenly, after 21 hours (time difference between the PG service restart and time on `backend_start` from `pg_stat_replication`) I find a record on `pg_stat_activity`  @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You can look at the log file of the standby server.

Comment: using `cat postgresql-12-main.log.1`, I find these : `2022-12-03 12:38:53.683 WIB [86421] FATAL:  terminating walreceiver due to timeout
2022-12-03 12:38:54.236 WIB [89062] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 9C8/F0000000 on timeline 1
2022-12-01 09:04:06.965 WIB [86219] FATAL:  terminating walreceiver due to timeout
2022-12-01 09:04:06.966 WIB [1911] LOG:  invalid record length at 9C4/DC3FB550: wanted 24, got 0` . What those indicate? @LaurenzAlbe